# can trac hook into a subversion repo that is on another server?

Tags: svn, trac

when using trac, I understand it lets you hook into subversion to see the source code etc. in the browser.

does the subversion repo have to be on the same server as the trac install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as such, but there is at least one workaround: [SVNSyncPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SvnsyncPlugin). It is not regarded totally stable though, read the notes on the page. I don't know of any other way to run trac with a remote svn repository.

Also, check out @techtonik's link in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to try Shun-ichi GOTO plugin for remote SVN access from http://www.meadowy.org/~gotoh/hg/remote-svn-plugin/

Comment: Otherwise the Subversion repository (at least for Trac 0.11) should be on the same server as Trac. See this TracFAQ entry at http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFaq#can-i-use-trac-with-a-remote-subversion-repository

Comment: It looks very interesting (I'm looking for something like that myself) but I'm a bit concerned it's dead (hasn't been updated for two years).

Comment: But you may use svnsync from http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnsync.html to create a local mirror. Set cronjob to run svnsync every 5 minutes or so to keep your copy updated. I did this for Trac that monitors Far Manager development at http://farmanager.rainforce.org/

Comment: SvnsyncPlugin is a wrapper for this svnsync, but I it doesn't seem to be useful to me http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SvnsyncPlugin

Comment: The best way to see if it is dead or not is to try.

Answer (score 1):

SvnsyncPlugin doesn't support svn 1.6.*, it just broken my repo, after trying to configure it.